# CarrierWave + Mini_Magick: undefined method `write' for "":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

Recently switched from RMagick to Mini_Magick. I am receiving the error `undefined method 'write' for "":String`. Here's what my uploader looks like...

```
class BackgroundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/backgrounds/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    "/assets/fallback/default.jpg"
  end

  process :resize_to_fit => [1024, 1024]
  process :convert => 'jpg'
  process :fix_exif_rotation

  def fix_exif_rotation
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient
      img = img.gaussian_blur 5
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

end
```

The issue lies in the `fix_exif_rotation` method. If I comment out the line `process :fix_exif_rotation` everything works just fine. I've removed the **!** from the end of the auto_orient call as that seems to have caused issues for others when switching from RMagick to Mini_Magick.

- [Related issue 1](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/68)
- [Related issue 2](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/436)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/436#issuecomment-10712270) comment from the above linked "Related issue 2" suggests assigning to img, except(!?) in the yield, could break things, so my first guess is to try just `img.gaussian_blur 5` instead of `img = img.gaussian_blur 5`.

Otherwise: Stack trace?

Comment: Ah ha! You're correct. Thanks for your help. Now the only thing is the value being passed in (5 in this case) seems to have no effect. Whether I provide none, 5, 50, 100...the outcome is the same blur radius. Any ideas there?

Comment: mini_magick is a pretty simple gem, so there isn't a lot that can go wrong. My ignorant guess is that the change just isn't visible. Based on the [imagemagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#gaussian-blur), maybe you should try parameters like "10x3", to indicate both a radius and a sigma.

Comment: Nailed it again. Thanks Taavo! For anyone else, these docs [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_args) really helped make sense of it all.